# socket.io onconnect send extra data

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io and currently everything is great however I want to send data to a specific client. However I am unsure how to get sed clients socket id. I want to send extra data on connection.

I have tried:

```
if (steamID != "" && steamName != "") {
    socket.emit("username", { 
        socketData: {
            name: steamName
        }
    });
}
```

and serverside:

```
socket.on('username', function (data) {
    socket.username = data.socketData.name;
});

clients[socket.id] = {
    id: socket.id,
    ip: socket.request.connection.remoteAddress,
    name: socket.username
    cons
}

console.log(clients);
```

However I just get name: undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In which part of your code you check the value of the `name` property? The code that you provide will first assign the value of undefined to `clients[socket.id].name`, since the `socket.username` is not defined yet. When the `on("username")` event is invoked then it will assign a value to `socket.username`. If you put a `console.log(data)` inside the message callback what do you get?

Comment: I have edited the question, console.log() comes just after clients. will check the callback now.

Comment: putting console.log(data) inside the socket.on('username', function (data) { gives: { socketData: { name: 'K1LzR' } } which is my username.

Comment: @Matt Then this is your problem. You will first have to wait until the callback is called and then use/define the `clients[socket.id]` object

Comment: I added clients[socket.id].name = socket.username; to the socket.on('username' and then when i called console.log(clients) further down in the script, when the socket.on has definitely been called it worked. thanks

Comment: @ Matt You are welcome :) Can you also accept as correct the answer since this solves your problem?